# Client_secret for grant_type = password

Tags: doorkeeper

Im using doorkeeper as an API for my iOS app. I would like to remove the need of a client_secret so the post parameters for a token would look like the following.

```
grant_type=password&
username=USERNAME&
password=PASSWORD&
client_id=CLIENT_ID
```

Help would be apprecieted!

Thanks,

Ludvig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set up an implicit grant

https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper/wiki/Supported-Features

you need to pass implicit_grant to doorkeeper.